# mod_zeropush stopped working in ejabberd 16.03

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am using mod_zeropush to send push to offline users that are offline in xmpp/ejabberd it was working fine with ejabberd version 15.07 but when i updated my version it stopped working and not hitting this given url.

```
2016-05-12 14:07:57.107 [warning] <0.809.0>@gen_mod:validate_opts:288 module 'mod_zeropush' doesn't export mod_opt_type/1
2016-05-12 14:07:57.107 [warning] <0.809.0>@gen_mod:validate_opts:288 module 'mod_zeropush' doesn't export mod_opt_type/1
2016-05-12 14:07:57.107 [warning] <0.809.0>@gen_mod:validate_opts:288 module 'mod_zeropush' doesn't export mod_opt_type/1
```

These are warnings it shows before starting module.

[Here is error log from ejabberd.log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192441/mod-zeropush-not-working-with-ejabberd-16-03/37192726#37192726)

Answer (score 0):

mod_zeropush does not support ejabberd 16.03 because it uses Fast XML instead of p1_xml so don't upgrade to 16.xx version stay with 15.xx